# Blank File When Attempting to Write to .txt In PHP via Form Input

Tags: php, forms

I cannot seem to figure out why my order.txt file is blank despite seemingly having my logic correct.  I'm new to PHP, so I apologize if I have obvious syntax errors.

I'm attempting to log the user input values of a form to a .txt file once the submit button is clicked.  Here is my code: **NOTE:** both my form and php script are in the same file, so the action is referring to itself.

HTML:

```
<form action="p1_checkout.php" method = "POST">
      First name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
      Last name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
      Street Address:<br>
      <input type="text" name="streetaddress"><br>
      City:<br>
      <input type="text" name="city"><br>
      State:<br>
      <input type="text" name="state"><br>
      Zip Code:<br>
      <input type="text" name="zipcode"><br>
      Phone Number:<br>
      <input type="text" name="phonenumber"><br>
      Order Quantity:<br>
      <input type="text" name="orderquantity"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Checkout">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
       <?php
            $newfile = fopen("order.txt", "w+");
            $fproduct = "Product: Mount Diablo, California Print";
            $fqty = "Quantity Ordered: ".$_POST['quantityordered'];
            $fname = "Person Billed: ".$_POST['firstname'];
            $faddress = "Address: ".$_POST['streetaddress'] + "," + $_POST['city'] + "," + $_POST['state'] + "," + $_POST['zipcode'];
            $fcontent = $fproduct + $fqty + $fname + $faddress;
            fwrite($newfile, $content);
            fclose($newfile);
        ?>
```

Comment: `fwrite($newfile, $fcontent);` write `fcontent`

Comment: Make sure you check if the post has been made (if(isset($_POST)) and check if the the variables are filled at all, You can also just use file_put_contents($file, $content);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to use [arithmetic operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

You need to concatenate vars, not add them.

this :

```
 $fcontent = $fproduct + $fqty + $fname + $faddress;
```

should be:

```
 $fcontent = "$fproduct $fqty $fname $faddress";
```

then write content to file:

```
fwrite($newfile, $fcontent); // you have typo, missing `f`
```

Make sure all $_POST values are ok though

EDIT: make **sure** $_POST values are correctly spelled : you use different name in form and in post result ->

```
$_POST['quantityordered'] != name="orderquantity" (in form)
```

and get rid of **all** arithmetic operators !

```
$faddress = "Address: ".$_POST['streetaddress'].", ".$_POST['city'].",". $_POST['state'] ."," .$_POST['zipcode'];
```

Comment: So this definitely made some progress!  I got some output, however, the results are odd.  This is what was returned: 

Product: Mount Diablo, California Print Quantity Ordered:  Person Billed: Cory 90650

It looks like the only thing that was successfully printed out was my name and zip code from the form.  Quantity ordered didn't result in anything, neither did address, zipcode, or state.

Comment: if running on the same page, put PHP code on top and add a statement like `if post values -> write file` (ie: add an ID to submit and check its $_POST value)

Comment: $_POST['quantityordered'] != name="orderquantity"

Comment: check updated answer -> you did **not** get rid of all `+`

Comment: Seemed to have fix it, thank you!  Looks like it was a silly typo and I was concating wrong. :)

Answer (score 3):

hey you are doing the slight mistake...
if you are using php in same file..
So, no need to give the file name in action leave it blank....

and for concatenation in php we don't use the

```
+ sign we use the DOT (.) sign...
```

here is the code..  try it....

```
    <form action="" method = "POST">
      First name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
      Last name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
      Street Address:<br>
      <input type="text" name="streetaddress"><br>
      City:<br>
      <input type="text" name="city"><br>
      State:<br>
      <input type="text" name="state"><br>
      Zip Code:<br>
      <input type="text" name="zipcode"><br>
      Phone Number:<br>
      <input type="text" name="phonenumber"><br>
      Order Quantity:<br>
      <input type="text" name="orderquantity"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Checkout" name="submit">
</form>


<?php
extract($_POST);
if(isset($submit))
{
$newfile = fopen("order.txt", "w+");
$fproduct = "Product: Mount Diablo, California Print";
$fqty = "Quantity Ordered: ".$orderquantity;
$fname = "Person Billed: ".$firstname;
$faddress = "Address: ".$streetaddress . "," . $city . "," . $state . "," . $zipcode;
$fcontent = $fproduct . $fqty . $fname . $faddress;
fwrite($newfile, $fcontent);
fclose($newfile);
}     
?>
```

Comment: that's exactly what was answered 10mn ago though ^^

Comment: its just a **coincidence** that previous code matches to my code....
but my code is slight different from previous code....

Answer (score 2):

```
     <?php
 if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
    $fproduct = "Product: Mount Diablo, California Print";
    $fqty = "Quantity Ordered: ".$_POST['quantityordered'];
    $fname = "Person Billed: ".$_POST['firstname'];
    $faddress = "Address: ".$_POST['streetaddress'] + "," + $_POST['city'] + "," + $_POST['state'] + "," + $_POST['zipcode'];
    $fcontent = $fproduct.' '.$fqty.' '.$fname.' '.$faddress;
    $fp = fopen("order.txt", 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $fcontent);
    fclose($fp);
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="p1_checkout.php" method = "POST">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
  Street Address:<br>
  <input type="text" name="streetaddress"><br>
  City:<br>
  <input type="text" name="city"><br>
  State:<br>
  <input type="text" name="state"><br>
  Zip Code:<br>
  <input type="text" name="zipcode"><br>
  Phone Number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="phonenumber"><br>
  Order Quantity:<br>
  <input type="text" name="orderquantity"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Checkout" name="Checkout">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
        <?php
          if(isset($_POST['Checkout']))
        {

        $newfile = fopen("order.txt", "w+");
        $fproduct = "Product: Mount Diablo, California Print ";
        $fqty = "Quantity Ordered: ".$_POST['orderquantity'];
        $fname = "Person Billed: ".$_POST['firstname'];
        $faddress = "Address: ".$_POST['streetaddress'] . "," .   $_POST['city'] . "," . $_POST['state'] . "," . $_POST['zipcode'];

        $fcontent = $fproduct . $fqty . $fname . $faddress;
        fwrite($newfile, $fcontent);
        fclose($newfile);
        }


  ?>
```